# websocket in esp32

Tags: javascript, html, c++, websocket, arduino-esp32

I am trying to make controller with esp32 board which is able to run websocket server. I found sample example but I want to edit it.

I want to upload the webpage in my website instead of the esp32 and then this page controls the esp32 instead of the example where the esp32 runs as webserver and providing the webpage via request in its ip address. I will post the example I found

```
//=====================================
//ESP32 WebSocket Server: DHT22 Sensor
//=====================================
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>
//---------------------------------------------------
DHT dht(32, DHT22);
//---------------------------------------------------
#define fanLED 2
#define humLED 4
#define SW     23
//---------------------------------------------------
const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";
//---------------------------------------------------
WebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);
//---------------------------------------------------
boolean fanLEDonoff=false; boolean humLEDonoff=false;
String JSONtxt;
//---------------------------------------------------
#include "webpage.h"
#include "functions.h"
//====================================================================
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(fanLED, OUTPUT); pinMode(humLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SW, INPUT);
  //-----------------------------------------------
  dht.begin();
  //-----------------------------------------------
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("."); delay(500);  
  }
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.print(" Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //-----------------------------------------------
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}
//====================================================================
void loop() 
{
  webSocket.loop(); server.handleClient();
  //----------------------------------------------------
  delay(2000);
  //----------------------------------------------------
  if(fanLEDonoff == false) digitalWrite(fanLED, LOW);
  else digitalWrite(fanLED, HIGH);
  String fanLEDstatus = "OFF";
  if(fanLEDonoff == true) fanLEDstatus = "ON";
  //----------------------------------------------------
  if(humLEDonoff == false) digitalWrite(humLED, LOW);
  else digitalWrite(humLED, HIGH);
  String humLEDstatus = "OFF";
  if(humLEDonoff == true) humLEDstatus = "ON";
  //----------------------------------------------------
  String SWstatus;
  if(digitalRead(SW) == HIGH) SWstatus = "ON";
  else SWstatus = "OFF";
  //----------------------------------------------------
  String TEMPvalString = String(dht.readTemperature());
  String HUMvalString = String(int(dht.readHumidity()));
  //----------------------------------------------------
  String humidifier, fan;
  if(dht.readTemperature() >= 25) fan = "ON";
  else fan = "OFF";
  if(int(dht.readHumidity()) < 40) humidifier = "ON";
  else humidifier = "OFF";
  //----------------------------------------------------
  JSONtxt  = "{\"TEMP\":\""+TEMPvalString+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"HUM\":\""+HUMvalString+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"fanLEDonoff\":\""+fanLEDstatus+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"humLEDonoff\":\""+humLEDstatus+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"SWonoff\":\""+SWstatus+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"FANonoff\":\""+fan+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"HUMonoff\":\""+humidifier+"\"}";
  //----------------------------------------------------
  webSocket.broadcastTXT(JSONtxt);
}

functions.h file:

//=======================================
//handle function: send webpage to client
//=======================================
void handleRoot()
{
  server.send(200,"text/html", webpageCont);
}
//=====================================================
//function process event: new data received from client
//=====================================================
void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t welength)
{
  String payloadString = (const char *)payload;
  //--------------------------------------------------
  if(type == WStype_TEXT)
  {
    byte separator=payloadString.indexOf('=');
    String var = payloadString.substring(0,separator);
    String val = payloadString.substring(separator+1);
    //------------------------------------------------
    if(var == "fanLEDonoff")
    {
      fanLEDonoff = false;
      if(val == "ON") fanLEDonoff = true;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------
    if(var == "humLEDonoff")
    {
      humLEDonoff = false;
      if(val == "ON") humLEDonoff = true;
    }
  }
}

webpage.h file:

//=========================================
//HTML, CSS & JavaScript Codes for Webpage
//=========================================
const char webpageCont[] PROGMEM = 
R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>ESP32 WebSocket Server</title>
<!------------------------------------------CSS----------------------------------------->
<style>
    #dynRectangle1
    {
        width:0px;
        height:12px;
        top: 9px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.863);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top: 1px;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }
    #dynRectangle2
    {
        width:0px;
        height:12px;
        top: 9px;
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.534);
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top:1px;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }
    body   {background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.322)}
    h1     {font-size: 40px; color: rgb(156, 5, 5); text-align:center; font-family:calibri}
    h2     {font-size: 25px; color: black; font-family:cursive}
    h3     {font-size: 17px; color:black; font-family:calibri}
    h4     {font-size: 14px; color: black; font-family:Trebuchet MS}
    div.h1 {background-color: whitesmoke;}
    .btn1  
    {
        background-color:#ff3c00b7;
        border: solid 2px rgb(10, 0, 0);
        color: white;
        padding: 4px 16px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
        width: 60px;
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 22px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        opacity: 0.6;
        transition: 0.3s;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .btn1:hover {opacity: 1}
    .btn2 
    {
        background-color:#002fffa4;
        border: solid 2px rgb(10, 0, 0);
        color: white;
        padding: 4px 16px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
        width: 60px;
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 22px;
        border-radius: 10%;
        opacity: 0.6;
        transition: 0.3s;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .btn2:hover {opacity: 1}
    span.b1 {float: left; padding: 5px 10px}
    span.b2 {float: left; padding: 5px 10px}
    .msgRect1
    {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 21px 1px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 120px;
        line-height: 10px;
        background-color:white;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .msgRect2
    {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 21px 1px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 120px;
        line-height: 10px;
        background-color:white;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .msgRect3
    {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 21px 1px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 120px;
        line-height: 10px;
        background-color:white;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>
<!-----------------------------------------HTML----------------------------------------->
<body>
    <h1><div class="h1">ESP32 WebSocket Server<br>DHT22 Temp & Humidity Sensor</div></h1>
    <h2>
        Temperature: <span style="color:rgb(216, 3, 3)" id="Tempvalue">0</span> C<br>
        Humidity&emsp;&emsp;: <span style="color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.795)" id="Humvalue">0</span> % 
    </h2>
    <h3>
        0 C &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; 50 C
        <div id="dynRectangle1"></div><br>
        0 % &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; 100 %
        <div id="dynRectangle2"></div>
    </h3>
    <h4>
        <span class="b1">
            Fan<br>
            <button class="btn1" id="FANbtn" onclick="fanONOFF()"> </button>
        </span>
        <span class="b2">
            Humidifier<br>
            <button class="btn2" id="HUMbtn" onclick="humONOFF()"> </button>
        </span>
        <span class="msgRect1" id="msg1""> </span>
        <span class="msgRect2" id="msg2""> </span>
        <span class="msgRect3" id="msg3""> </span>
    </h4>
</body>
<!-------------------------------------JavaScript--------------------------------------->
<script>
  InitWebSocket()
  function InitWebSocket()
  {
    websock = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':81/');
    websock.onmessage=function(evt)
    {
       JSONobj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
       document.getElementById('Tempvalue').innerHTML = JSONobj.TEMP;
       var temp = parseInt(JSONobj.TEMP * 9.5);
       document.getElementById("dynRectangle1").style.width = temp+"px";
       
       document.getElementById('Humvalue').innerHTML = JSONobj.HUM;
       var hum = parseInt(JSONobj.HUM * 4.8);
       document.getElementById("dynRectangle2").style.width = hum+"px";

       document.getElementById('FANbtn').innerHTML = JSONobj.fanLEDonoff;
       document.getElementById('HUMbtn').innerHTML = JSONobj.humLEDonoff;
       
       document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = JSONobj.FANonoff;
       if(JSONobj.FANonoff == 'ON')
       {
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Fan ON";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect1")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FFFF33";
       }
       else
       {
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Fan OFF";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect1")[0].style.backgroundColor="#00BFFF";
       }
       
       document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = JSONobj.HUMonoff;
       if(JSONobj.HUMonoff == 'ON')
       {
        document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Humidifier ON";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect2")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FFFF33";
       }
       else
       {
        document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML="Humidifier OFF";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect2")[0].style.backgroundColor="#00BFFF";
       }

       document.getElementById('msg3').innerHTML = JSONobj.SWonoff;
       if(JSONobj.SWonoff == 'ON')
       {
        document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Check Server";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect3")[0].style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
       }
       else
       {
        document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML="Server OK";
        document.getElementsByClassName("msgRect3")[0].style.backgroundColor="#90EE90";
       }
    }
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function fanONOFF()
  {
    FANbtn = 'fanLEDonoff=ON';
    if(document.getElementById('FANbtn').innerHTML == 'ON')
    {
      FANbtn = 'fanLEDonoff=OFF';
    }
    websock.send(FANbtn);
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function humONOFF()
  {
    HUMbtn = 'humLEDonoff=ON';
    if(document.getElementById('HUMbtn').innerHTML == 'ON')
    {
      HUMbtn = 'humLEDonoff=OFF';
    }
    websock.send(HUMbtn);
  }
</script>
</html>
)=====";
```

this is the example

should I edit those first :

```
server.on("/", handleRoot);

//this void hadleRoot is in the functions.h file
void handleRoot()
{
  server.send(200,"text/html", webpageCont);
}
```

to give it my webpage link instead of webpageCont which is the page code written in this code, and then in the webpage itself I edit the websocket here

```
InitWebSocket()
  function InitWebSocket()
  {
    websock = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':81/');
    websock.onmessage=function(evt)
    {
       JSONobj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
```

To change window.location.hostname to my esp32 IP address? What topic I should read to understand this and how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts to websocket use in these scenarios.

1. Websocket server.
2. Websocket client.
3. HTML page which is hosting Websocket client.

Websocket server in your case is on ESP32 running `<host>:81`.
Websocket client is running inside the html file using `javascript` and usually its also hosted inside the same ESP32 webserver. That's the reason you see the url mentioned as `${window.location.hostname}`. This just means both websocket and html is coming from same hostname.

If you move the HTML (Websocket client) to external server, the only requirement would be changing the url

```js
websock = new WebSocket('ws://<device-ip-address>:81/');
```

Here are the basic requirement for the javscript client.

```js
// Your IP address instead of ${window.location.hostname}
var wsurl = `ws://<device-ip-address>:81/`;
var websocket;

// Add a listener to initialize websocket on page load
window.addEventListener('load', onload);

// On page load, initialize websocket
function onload(event) {
    initWebSocket();
}

// Setup all the required callback functions for the websocket events
function initWebSocket() {
    console.log('Trying to open a WebSocket connection…');
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsurl);
    websocket.onopen = onOpen;
    websocket.onclose = onClose;
    websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
}

// Connected
function onOpen(event) {
    console.log('Connected');
}

// Disconnected
function onClose(event) {
    console.log('Disconnected');
}

// Show the received message 
function onMessage(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}
```

Note: Make sure you are on the same local network while testing, since ESP32 works on 2.4GHz Wi-Fi, so your PC should be connected to same AP and not 5GHz.